# Format date output difference PHP

Tags: php

I am having problem with my date format which is the value get from SQL databases and pass to the form for the user and in return when user set it back to store into databases the format is gone difference.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $memberTable WHERE id='11' LIMIT 1"); //checking from SQL
$sqlcheck = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); //Pass each value

$dob = strftime("%Y-%B-%d", strtotime($sqlcheck['dob']));
//format from databases 2000-10-30 into 2000-October-30

$dob = explode("-", $dob);
// break into day,month,year for form to fill in

$dob = $dob[0].'-'.$dob[1].'-'.$dob[2];
// after user fill in combine together for user to input back to databases

$dob = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($dob));
//formatting back into databases format, 2000-October-30 into 2000-10-30
//The main problem here is the output is "2000-10-02"
```

I am wondering why the day value pass becoming 02 instead of 30 ?
is that something wrong with the format code I am using ?
Please Help.

Comment: Just because you can build a format with `strftime` doesn’t mean `strtotime` can understand it.

Comment: After you convert 2000-10-30 to 2000-October-30, you use strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($dob));. The problem is here. Right. recommend is don't convert to 2000-October-30. Then, use directly strftime();.Correct result will show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ you just not making the write date format for the `strtotime()` function you can do it right  like this :-

```
$date='2000-October-30';
$dob = explode("-", $date);
$dob = $dob[2].'-'.$dob[1].'-'.$dob[0];
echo $dob = strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($dob));
```

you can check for php date and time format [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: Thx for your answers, I knew my problem now.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `date` function like

```
echo $dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dob));
```

And better to use like(optional)

```
$dob = strtotime("Y-B-d", strtotime($sqlcheck['dob']));
//format from databases 2000-10-30 into 2000-October-30

$dob = explode("-", $dob);
// break into day,month,year for form to fill in

$dateofbirth = $dob[0].'-'.$dob[1].'-'.$dob[2];
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateofbirth));
```

Answer (score 0):

The strtotime method calculates the date correctly if the format is "`2013-Oct-30`" 
but does not calculate it when the date is in the format "`2013-October-30`"

When you are building the date back together just do a substring on the month to get the first 3 characters of the month and that should fix your issue.

```
$dob = $dob[0].'-'. substr($dob[1], 0, 3) .'-'.$dob[2];
```

// after user fill in combine together for user to input back to databases